# html email css selector why use them

Tags: css

I see a lot of html emails and they have CSS like this:

```
*[class].w320
```

Now I think I understand CSS selectors, but to me the above does not really make sense because you are not really targeting anything.  Isn't the above the same as simply doing this?

```
.w320
```

Any thoughts why they use the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually using square brackets (attribute selectors) is a fix for yahoo mail.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Answer (score 1):

I know you understand the selectors, but just a description of what they do:

This selects **`all elements with a class attribute and that also are members of the w320 class`**

```
*[class].w320
```

And this simply selects **`all elements with class of .w320`**

```
.w320
```

---

You can see **[Email Clients' CSS Support Here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)**

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of taste. The former is unnecessarily verbose and quite possibly slower.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah that is what I thought at first.

Comment: "all elements with a class attribute of .w320" — No, it selects all elements with a class attribute (with any value whatsoever) that also are members of the `w320` class.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, updated the answer, so it doesn't make it same, i guess ?

Comment: By spec, aside from specificity, the selectors are identical. Hmm. I suppose there might be a difference between a class added programatically and one added in the raw HTML, but I thought that DOM said the attribute should update for that one.